# Apply get set for methods?

Tags: c#

I have just learned **get set** principles in C# and I wonder whether there is any interest of using the same principle for methods.

If I understand well, get and set are used for variables. But it could be possible to apply the same principle for methods. For instance:

```
private int _GiveMultiply()
{
  int a = ...
  int b = ...
  return c = a*b;
}

public int GiveMultiply
{
  get { return _GiveMultiply(); }
}
```

But is there any kind of interest to do such a thing ?
For example is there a risk to use a public function that can be prevented using such a process ?

Comment: What purpose does this solve?  It makes very little sense

Comment: No, you didn't understand well. The `get` and `set` keywords are for properties, not for variables. You can't use `get` for methods.

Comment: You have an extra set of parentheses in there that don't belong, and suggest you don't fully understand how a property affects the syntax at the call point.

Comment: Probably you  haven't seen any method that accepts parameters yet, that's why you get confused !

Comment: In a method, there'd be no need to use `get`. You can simply write `public int GiveMultiply() => _GiveMultiply()`. And no, it makes no sense as written, since the methods would do the same thing with no further encapsulation, so you might as well just have `GiveMultiply` on its own. There are scenarios where it makes sense to have public methods that do their work by calling private methods, of course, but then they do a little more work than just forwarding.

Comment: Properties enable a class to expose a public way of getting and setting values, while hiding implementation or verification code.  The fundamental core to a property.

Comment: What would it mean to `set` a method? How would `get` be different than `return` (which is how methods currently return a value)? You ask, *"is there any kind of interest to do such a thing"*, but you haven't really defined what *"such a thing"* means.

Comment: By such a thing I mean using get and set. I am wondering if using a public method could make a problem (like access to inner variables etc) but considering the answers I think not.

Comment: You *can* have a property that is a delegate (that is, a function): `public Func<int, int, int> Multiplier { get; set; }`, and then `.Multiplier = (a, b) => a * b`. Such a delegate has no access to members of the class, as it's not a member. But that use case is very unusual and specific -- a more common instance of this is when you use [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/events/), which are basically properties that are lists of delegates, and only support adding and removing delegates to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it depends. I'll try to help you to reformulate your question: does it make any sense to return a **function** rather than **computed result** from another fuction? Then I would say: definitely yes (let me know if you'd like to know ehy, I'll update this post). But the example you showed does not return a fuction, it just wraps it into yet another fuction, which is useless. The only exception is various kinds of **abstract method** patterns, where you might have public function with some predefined logic and call to the abstract/virtual fuctions; rarely they do have same name, then indeed wrapping sort of works.

Comment: My question was just around the interest to make an equivalent of get and set for functions (with a function that returns a result). Seems not !